# How to put one word into a json tree, if the word exist?

Tags: php, json

Here is a json tree.

```
[
 {"name":"foo"},
 {"name":"bar"},
 {"name":"Hello"}
]
```

How to put one word into a json tree, to match if the word exist? like this:

```
$word = 'foo'; //'title'

if(...){ 
//if 'foo' is exist in the json tree, do some stuff
} else{
//if 'title' is not exist in the json tree, do something here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
$word = 'foo';
$data = json_decode($tree);

$found = false;
foreach($tree as $element) {
   if ($element['name'] == $word) {
      $found = true;
      break;
   }
}
if (!$found) {
    die("Word not found");
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to pass true as the second parameter of json_decode, so it will produce an associative array instead of an object. Otherwise you need to change the code to $element->name

Answer (score 1):

First your need to convert the JSON code to a valid PHP data type using **[json_decode](http://ca.php.net/json_decode)**. Once you have a valid PHP data type, like an array for instance, you will be able to loop through its values or use one of PHP array functions to search it.

If you transform it into an array, you can easily insert new values like this (keeping the same structure of your example):

```
$tree[]['name'] = 'Hi';
```

Once you are done, use **[json_encode](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** to get a JSON representation of your new tree.

Comment: excuse me, how to do in your method? As I know, it should put some number in the `[]`, make it like `$tree[0]['name']` and so so...

Comment: if you do not specify an index for the array PHP will create a new element for you, so you don't need to know how many elements you have in your array.

Comment: ok, i know now, thanks, but Marc B is first answer and his reply can work well. so just give +1 to u.